# How do you re-run failed mocha tests in the WebStorm IDE?

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I'm using a Mocha Run/Debug configuration in WebStorm 11.0.3. I can see all my passing and failing tests in the panel at the bottom.

According to [WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/test-runner-tab.html?page=1), I can "rerun the tests" or "stop and rerun the tests", but I don't see an option to only rerun tests that failed.

A Google search shows that "rerun failed tests" exists in [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/test-runner-tab.html?origin=old_help) and [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/test-runner-tab.html#runToolbar), two other JetBrains products. Perhaps they just left it out of WebStorm?

If it's not a built-in feature, is there a way to do this with mocha, perhaps by creating a report and reading the report on each run?

Comment: Accordingly to the [tickets](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13764) the rerun should be available. Try `Help | Find Action...` and look for `rerun` action there -- see if it's enabled or not, what shortcut it has etc.

Comment: simple rerun is available, but not 'rerun failed'; this feature can only be implemented if there is a possibility to run individual tests. As this possibility has been recently provided for Mocha, it's possible to add 'rerun failed' for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no '`Rerun Failed Tests`' action available for Mocha. Would be a useful feature, please feel free to file a request for it to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)

Answer (score 0):

In fact "ReRun Failed Tests" for Mocha tests is now available in WebStorm.

see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/rerunning-tests.html
[image]